# Create column identifying minimum character from within a group and label ties

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, subset

I have paired data for 10 subjects (with some missing and some ties).  My goal is to select the `eye` with the best `disc_grade` (A > B > C) and label ties accordingly from the data frame below.

I'm stuck on how to use R code to select the rows with the best `disc_grade` for each subject.

```
df <- structure(list(patientID = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 
6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10), eye = c("R", "L", "R", "L", "R", 
"L", "R", "L", "R", "L", "R", "L", "R", "L", "R", "L", "R", "L", 
"R", "L"), disc_grade = c(NA, "B", "C", "B", "B", "C", "B", "C", 
"B", "A", "B", "B", "C", "B", NA, NA, "B", "C", "B", "C")), .Names = c("patientID", "eye", "disc_grade"), class = c("tbl_df", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

The desired output is:

```
   patientID   eye disc_grade
2          1   L          B
4          2   L          B
5          3   R          B
7          4   R          B
10         5   L          A
11         6   Tie        B
14         7   L          B
17         9   R          B
19        10   R          B
```

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(patientID) %>% 
  filter(disc_grade == min(disc_grade, na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
  summarise(eye = if (n()==1) eye else "Tie", disc_grade = first(disc_grade))

  patientID   eye disc_grade
      (dbl) (chr)      (chr)
1         1     L          B
2         2     L          B
3         3     R          B
4         4     R          B
5         5     L          A
6         6   Tie          B
7         7     L          B
8         9     R          B
9        10     R          B
```

There is a warning for group 8, but we get the desired result thanks to how `filter` works on `NA`s.

---

With data.table:

```
setDT(df)[, 
  .SD[ disc_grade == min(disc_grade, na.rm=TRUE) ][,
    .( eye = if (.N==1) eye else "Tie", disc_grade = disc_grade[1] )
  ]
, by=patientID]
```

Again, there's a warning, but now we do get a row for group 8, since `[` does not ignore `NA`s. To get around this, you could filter the NAs before or after the operation (as in other answers). My best idea for doing it during the main operation is pretty convoluted:

```
setDT(df)[, 
  .SD[ which(disc_grade == min(disc_grade, na.rm=TRUE)) ][,
    if (.N >= 1) list( eye = if (.N==1) eye else "Tie", disc_grade = disc_grade[1] )
  ]
, by=patientID]
```

Answer (score 2):

One option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
na.omit(setDT(df))[, eye:=if(uniqueN(disc_grade)==1 & 
            .N >1)  'Tie'  else eye, patientID
         ][order(factor(disc_grade, levels=c('A', 'B', 'C'))),
              .SD[1L] ,patientID][order(patientID)]
#    patientID eye disc_grade
#1:         1   L          B
#2:         2   L          B
#3:         3   R          B
#4:         4   R          B
#5:         5   L          A
#6:         6 Tie          B
#7:         7   L          B
#8:         9   R          B
#9:        10   R          B
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)

df <- structure(list(patientID = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 
                                   6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10), eye = c("R", "L", "R", "L", "R", 
                                                                         "L", "R", "L", "R", "L", "R", "L", "R", "L", "R", "L", "R", "L", 
                                                                         "R", "L"), disc_grade = c(NA, "B", "C", "B", "B", "C", "B", "C", 
                                                                                                   "B", "A", "B", "B", "C", "B", NA, NA, "B", "C", "B", "C")), .Names = c("patientID", "eye", "disc_grade"), class = c("tbl_df", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L))



df %>%
  filter(!is.na(disc_grade)) %>%                     ## remove rows with NAs
  group_by(patientID) %>%                            ## for each patient
  filter(disc_grade == min(disc_grade)) %>%          ## keep the row (his eye) that has the best score
  mutate(eye_upd = ifelse(n() > 1, "tie", eye)) %>%  ## if you kept both eyes you have a tie
  select(patientID,eye_upd,disc_grade) %>%
  distinct()

#    patientID eye_upd disc_grade
#        (dbl)   (chr)     (fctr)
# 1         1       L          B
# 2         2       L          B
# 3         3       R          B
# 4         4       R          B
# 5         5       L          A
# 6         6     tie          B
# 7         7       L          B
# 8         9       R          B
# 9        10       R          B
```

Comment: Extremely similar to @JasonAizkalns :-)

Answer (score 0):

There's certainly a better way to do this, but this gets the job done...need more coffee...

```
df_orig <- df

library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(!is.na(disc_grade)) %>%
  group_by(patientID) %>%
  summarise(best = min(disc_grade)) %>%
  left_join(., df_orig, by = c("patientID" = "patientID",
                               "best" = "disc_grade")) %>%
  group_by(patientID) %>%
  mutate(eye = ifelse(n() > 1, "tie", eye)) %>%
  distinct(patientID) %>% 
  select(patientID, eye, best)
```

*Note: I am able to get away with `min(disc_grade)` because of type conversation. Consider looking at `as.numeric(as.factor(df$disc_grade))`.*