# Create column with minimum (first) level of factors by group r

Tags: r, dplyr, r-factor

I have a data frame with a mixture of patient and appointment information. Each patient may have attended multiple appointments. Some patient information is collected at each appointment, with the result that some patient information is conflicting and some is missing.

I want to fill in the missing patient information for appointments where it wasn't recorded based upon data recorded at other appointments. And (this is where I'm stuck) I want to take the 'minimum' level (earliest in order of levels) recorded for factors that have conflicting information for the same patient. (In the example below the factor levels are in alphabetical order , but this isn't always the case).

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33568497/4241780), but I am using factors instead of characters, and I have multiple factors that I want the minimum for so can't filter by row.

eg. I have

```
df.have <- data.frame(
  grp_id = rep(1:3, each = 2),
  grpvar1 = factor(c("B", "A", "B", "C", NA, "A")),
  grpvar2 = factor(c("a", "b", "c", NA, NA, "x")),
  appt_id = 1:6)
```

I want

```
grp_id grpvar1   grpvar2 appt_id
     1       A         a       1
     1       A         a       2
     2       B         c       3
     2       B         c       4
     3       A         x       5
     3       A         x       6
```

or at least

```
grp_id grpvar1 grpvar1.1
     1       A         a
     2       B         c
     3       A         x
```

Comment: Explain why you made the changes that you did so we understand the rule. You switched a `B` to an A in the first row. Why?

Comment: posted a solution below, please check if it works

Comment: @PierreLafortune Because they both have the same grp_id, and A comes before B in the grpvar1 factor levels. This is what I meant by 'minimum' of the factor levels, but I couldn't think of a better way of explaining it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try with `summarise_each`.  As we need the first `level` of 'grpvar' variables, we need to make sure that the unused levels are dropped before we do that (using `droplevels`).

```
df.have %>% 
     group_by(grp_id) %>% 
     summarise_each(funs(first(levels(droplevels(.)))), grpvar1:grpvar2)
#   grp_id grpvar1 grpvar2
#   <int>   <chr>   <chr>
#1      1       A       a
#2      2       B       c
#3      3       A       x
```

Or if we use `mutate_each`, we get the first output

```
df.have %>% 
    group_by(grp_id) %>%
    mutate_each(funs(levels(droplevels(.))[1]), grpvar1:grpvar2)    
#  grp_id grpvar1 grpvar2 appt_id
#   <int>   <chr>   <chr>   <int>
#1      1       A       a       1
#2      1       A       a       2
#3      2       B       c       3
#4      2       B       c       4
#5      3       A       x       5
#6      3       A       x       6
```

if we need the output as `factor` columns for 'grpvar's.

```
 df.have %>% 
    group_by(grp_id) %>%
    mutate_each(funs(factor(levels(droplevels(.))[1])), grpvar1:grpvar2)    
 #   grp_id grpvar1 grpvar2 appt_id
 #    <int>  <fctr>  <fctr>   <int>
 #1      1       A       a       1
 #2      1       A       a       2
 #3      2       B       c       3
 #4      2       B       c       4
 #5      3       A       x       5
 #6      3       A       x       6
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df.have)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) levels(droplevels(x))[1]) , 
                grp_id, .SDcols = grpvar1:grpvar2]
```

Comment: Beautiful. The one drawback is that the input factors are converted to character variables. But they can be converted back using `for(var in vars)
  df.want[, var] <- factor(as.data.frame(df.want)[,var], levels = levels(df.have[,var]))` (or something more elegant?!)

Comment: @JWilliman  Because we are only getting the `levels` and not the `factor` as such, it is a `character` variable.

Comment: @JWilliman  If we want to convert to `factor`, just wrap `factor` around the `levels` i.e. `df.have %>% group_by(grp_id) %>% summarise(grpvar1 = factor(levels(droplevels(grpvar1))[1]))` replace the `summarise` with `summarise_each`.

Answer (score 0):

While revisiting this for a different project with a larger dataset I realised that it was much more efficient (though required more keystrokes) to convert the factors to numbers, take the minimum, then reconvert back to factors.

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(1)
n <- 100L

dat <- data.table(
  grp_id = rep(1:n/10, each = 10),
  grpvar1 = factor(sample(c(LETTERS, NA), n, replace = TRUE), levels = LETTERS),
  grpvar2 = factor(sample(c(letters, NA), n, replace = TRUE), levels = letters),
  appt_id = 1:n)

cols <- c("grpvar1","grpvar2")

dplyr_fct <- function(data, cols) {
  data %>% 
    group_by(grp_id) %>%
    mutate_each(funs(factor(levels(droplevels(.))[1])), one_of(cols))
}

dt_fct <- function(data, cols) {
  data[, lapply(.SD, function(x) levels(droplevels(x))[1]), grp_id, .SDcols = cols]}

dt_nmbr <- function(data, cols) {
  dat_out <- copy(data)
  v_lvl = lapply(dat_out[, .SD, .SDcols = cols], levels)
  # Convert factors to numeric
  for(col in cols) set(dat_out, j = col, value = as.numeric(dat_out[[col]]))
  # Select highest value
  dat_out[, (cols):= lapply(.SD, min, na.rm = TRUE), by = grp_id, .SDcols = cols]
  # Convert back to factor
  for(col in cols) set(dat_out, j = col, 
                       value = factor(dat_out[[col]], levels = 1:length(v_lvl[[col]]), labels = v_lvl[[col]]))
  assign("dat_out", dat_out, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}

mbm <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  mbm_dplyr_fct = dplyr_fct(dat, cols),
  mbm_dt_fct    = dt_fct(dat, cols),
  mbm_dt_nmbr   = dt_nmbr(dat, cols)
)

mbm

Unit: milliseconds
          expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
 mbm_dplyr_fct 84.487484 85.829834 90.988740 87.015878 91.159178 120.22171   100   c
    mbm_dt_fct 56.768529 58.007094 60.988083 58.831850 60.269427  87.11799   100  b 
   mbm_dt_nmbr  4.181538  4.406392  4.540248  4.557948  4.619757   6.04197   100 a
```